# Random errors when doing asynchronous calls to Magento from Javascript

Tags: ajax, zend-framework, magento, jquery

I'm currently building an extension on top of Magento, a part of it is an API which allows other sites to grab information from my extension. These calls will be Cross-origin, but I'm not worrying about authentication for now, making the Cross-origin resource sharing simpler to setup.

I'm calling a mixture of css, html, json, and sometimes images using the api. Whenever I do these calls asynchrously there is about a 5% chance of failure due to a random error for each call. Here's a list of the errors I'm receiving:

- **500 Server Error**: Just a general server error, could be many things
- **404 Error**: I'm guessing the router didn't load properly
- **Origin Null**: "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin". This is caused by the server not reaching the part where I set my origin allowed header to *.
- **Empty String**: Sometimes it works, but just returns an empty string instead of the asset I'm trying to grab.
- **Thrown Magento Error** Example!

```
Module "TBT_RewardsCoreSpending" requires module "TBT_RewardsCoreCustomer".
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token _sortModuleDepends(Array)
#2 C:\Users\Skaught\ST\me11110\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(315): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_loadDeclaredModules()
#3 C:\Users\Skaught\ST\me11110\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(409): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModules()
#4 C:\Users\Skaught\ST\me11110\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(338): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#5 C:\Users\Skaught\ST\me11110\app\Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 C:\Users\Skaught\ST\me11110\index.php(77): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}
```

As soon as I make these calls synchronous, the errors go away. However, this isn't a viable solution due to the amount of calls I need to make. When I dive and break point through the Magento code it seems to break in random parts for each error.

If you have any insight on where I should look for cause of this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a shot in the dark, but those errors sound like the configuration object is, occasionally, failing to completely load.  The 500 errors could be anything (check your apache logs; also, run Magento in developer mode with the display_error ini set to `1`), the 404 errors could be caused by a frontend section failing to load, and the thrown Magento error makes it look like the `TBT_RewardsCoreCustomer` Sweet Tooth module has failed to load into your configuration.

[I wrote](http://alanstorm.com/magento_config_a_critique_and_caching) about this issue before in a [longer series](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento#magento_config) of articles, but the short version is: Sometimes if Magento has trouble loading its configuration files from disk and/or Cache (and the default cache is disk), entire sections can be missing.  I know that, out of the box, windows machines used to have serious file locking issues with Apache/PHP (no idea if this is still the case).  My guess is your local machine can't handle the number of asynchronous calls you're making, the cache fails to load, and you get your errors/weird behavior.

There's no easy solution.  Personally, I'd switch up your development environment to a *nix installation of some sort, since that's what Magento will be deployed to anyway.  Virtual Box and Ubuntu are your friends.  You could try turning cache off on your local installation   , or switching to an in-memory cache backend instead of a disk backend.  If your problem is the one I described in those articles this should alleviate the problems somewhat.  Finally, you can always architect your asynchronous solution such that the success or failure of any one call doesn't bork whatever it is you're trying to do.

Good luck.

Comment: Thought this might be the case. Thanks for the articles, they are very well written. Now that I know these errors are inherent with Magento, and our prod environment seems ideal for mitigate these errors, I can move forward and just keep this in mind when design my requests. Awesome! Alan Storm, you are, and continue to be, a gentlemen and a scholar.